# how to watch object state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my app code:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(() => {
    return {
        flag1: false,
        flag2: false
    }
})

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myState)
}, [myState])

setMyState({ ...myState, flag1: true })
```

Last row triggers useEffect() but console output shows old state:

```
{flag1: false, flag2: false}
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to watch when all flag fields and once these are true - then I'll execute some code in useEffect. What would be best approach to do it?

Comment: on which method did you call `setMyState`?

Comment: The effect callback runs *after* a render, and a state update triggers a rerender, the console log in the effect will be the current state. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a function in useState.

Use prevState in setMyState, this way you will get the current state values

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState( {
        flag1: false,
        flag2: false
    });

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myState)
}, [myState])

setMyState(prevState=>({ ...prevState, flag1: true }));
```

Comment: Lazy state initialization is still ok though, albeit probably unnecessary in this simplified example, and IMO not an issue here. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I totally agree.